# Get Y value from a mesh or mesh vertices without raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I been stuck at this specific problem and have not been able to rack my head around it.

Easiest way to describe my problem is I have a 100 by 100 mesh that is randomly generated along the Y value points. I THEN spawn in trees rocks grass ect depending on the room value. The problem I have is I have been unable to successfully get the Y value of the plane at the specific location.

I have tried raycast and return the value unfortunately it is too slow as my world is 100% randomly generated in chunks and tends to mess up. I also tried attaching the objects to a plane then set that plane equal to to the mesh but unity combine meshes is not suitable for the amount of objects I have on the plane.

I was wondering if I could somehow compare mesh vertices with the game object x and z to return a Y.

Update*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6gP7.jpg)

And the search continues.

Comment: You can iterate over the vertices of a mesh to examine their positions: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html.  To access the vertex normals of a specific vertex, first find it in the mesh.vertices array then look at the normal in at the same index in the mesh.normals array.

Comment: Huh Interesting , I did this when I created and edited the vertices of the plane, can you get the world position from meah.normal vertices hmmm didnt even think about that I though only the transform help the position. Thank you ill look into when I have time and let you know the results!

Comment: Well I am back sir, been reading about it and have not been able to figure out precisely why its not converting. I debug it at it keeps saying local values. I might put this particular problem on hold as im not progressing in it. Ill update the question and add. Picture.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [tour] and [ask]. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Sorry, I probably only led you half the way there.  You will need to convert the position of the vertex to world space e.g  
`Matrix 4x4 localToWorld = yourMeshObject.transform.localToWorldMatrix;` then loop through the vertices or select one somehow and `Vector3 worldSpacePos = localToWorld.MultiplyPoint3x4(yourMeshVertex);`